# XTR111 4-20mA to 0-10V issue

Tags: dac, 4-20ma

I have below circuit which produce 4-20mA and by adding resistor (before the TVS) I can get

- 50ohm => 0-1V
- 250ohm => 0-5V
- but unable to get 0-10V since when I add 500ohm resistor, the voltage max out at 5.62

Why this is happening how can be fixed,

I have Dac out put is 0-3v and my Vref is 3V to.

[image]

This design is base on [XTR111EVM](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sbou048c/sbou048c.pdf) 
XTR111 [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr111.pdf)

"Q18 is an external transistor (QEXT) that
forms a cascode for the current output"

I even removed the D18 ans still same problem

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. But it will be difficult to get 20mA on 500 ohm load with 12V supply voltage. Not clear why the output capacitor is needed and all this double protection stuff.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I am trying to figure out why I am not able to get 0-10V from 0-20mA. base on Figure 48 on XTR111 datasheet  you should be able to get 0-10V output. I will test circuit with 24v power supply and let you know if that fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. From the [datasheet](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/CDSOD323-TxxC.pdf).*

The CDSOD323-T05C appears to be working perfectly.

You need the T12 or T12C.

Comment: That is good point but even if I remove the D18 from the circuit still I am not getting 0-10V  the voltage clam on 5.6V

Comment: You need to add that into your question then, along with links to the datasheets for the likely culprits. You might also want to explain what Q18 and Q3 are supposed to be doing and what the voltage at VG is.

Comment: @Shahreza: I notice that you still haven't provided a measurement for the voltage at VG while you're expecting 20 mA. It's important to read the comments carefully and try and provide the information requested.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I just Measure VG which 7.68V